# Remove repo after adding it via deb

Tags: ppa

I've added a repo with the following:

```
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe"
```

How would I remove it? I'm using this in a automated script also!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'd consider it a bad idea to remove a repo after installing a package from it -- doing so will prevent getting updates when they're available.

Answer (score 0):

Repos are listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Simply create a backup of that file (for safety) and remove the repo(s) you no longer want.